# how to configure my saml service provider to client login page

Tags: php, saml-2.0

In SAML SSO contain 3 stages IDP( Identity Provider ) - SP (Service Provider) - Client server. I have done the implementation of IDP and SP in my 2 sites as per simplesamlphp.org installation steps. Its communicating well and working properly. Now I need implement the Client server site. I didnt get any clue. I dont know where i genrate that access code or that login form. Please help to solve this problem.

Comment: how client interacts with server at SP level ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the answer from myself. Yes my guess is correct, after the same installation did on the client side, the communication is worked well. Now the problem is solved